# Problem with exporting plot in .pdf

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I have Mathematica 13.1. I am making the following plot:

```
Show[ListLogLogPlot[{ExcludedRegionHNLe, BBNHNLse, DVleHL, DVseHL, 
   LHCbeHL, FCCee4events}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.004], Gray}, {Thickness[0.004], 
     Gray}, {Thickness[0.003], Blue, 
     Dashing[0.02]}, {Thickness[0.003], Blue}, {Thickness[0.004], 
     Darker@Darker@Green}, {Thickness[0.004], 
     Darker@Red}, {Thickness[0.002], Darker@Cyan, Dashing[0.02]}}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 42], 
  Joined -> {True, True, True, True, True}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 76}, {10^-13, 10^-3.1}}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 0.66, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(N\)]\) [GeV]", 
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(e\)], \(2\)]\)"}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {Top, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.3]]}, 
    2 -> {Bottom, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.1]]}, 
    3 -> {True, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.05]]}, 
    4 -> {True, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.05]]}, 
    5 -> {True, Directive[Darker@Darker@Green, Opacity[0.05]]}, 
    6 -> {True, Directive[Darker@Red, Opacity[0.05]]}}(*,
  PlotLabel\[Rule]Style["Solid: @LHC, dashed: @FCC",16,Black]*), 
  FrameTicks -> {{"Log", None}, {"Log", None}}], 
 Graphics[{Text[Style["Excluded", 48, Black], Scaled[{0.8, 0.9}]], 
   Text[Style["BBN", 40, Gray], Scaled[{0.05, 0.38}], 
    Left, {3, -2.9}], 
   Text[Style["Seesaw", 40, Gray], Scaled[{0.45, 0.16}], 
    Left, {3, -0.4}], 
   Text[Style["FCC-ee", 32, Darker@Red], Scaled[{0.8, 0.75}], 
    Left, {3, -2.9}], 
   Text[Style["ATLAS/CMS", 32, Blue], Scaled[{0.6, 0.45}], 
    Left, {3, -0.9}], 
   Text[Style["LHCb", 32, Darker@Darker@Green], Scaled[{0.15, 0.695}],
     Left, {3, -1.}], 
   Text[Style["Inaccessible by colliders", 44, Black], 
    Scaled[{0.1, 0.55}], Left, {3, -1.3}]}]]
```

In Mathematica, it looks as

[image]

However, when exporting it as .pdf, some problems arise (note the vertical blue strip as well as the absence of "-" and "/" in abbreviations):
[image]

Could you please tell me how to export this figure properly?

P.S. This problem is present only in 13.1. It is not present in 12.X versions.

Comment: "vertical blue strip" you mean almost invisable line on the right that goes through F letter in FCC?

Comment: You haven't provided all of the definitions required to reproduce your plot. With just the definitions provided, the plot (including the "/" and "-")  is exported and imported without a problem using `"13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`